# sys.extended.ui is null or not an object sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, ajax, ajax-control-tookit

I'm working in SharePoint 2010 and using ajax toolkit 3.0.30930.28736

I'm using the ajax toolkit slider control. For some reason I wanted to override the following method of slider

```
 Sys.Extended.UI.SliderBehavior.prototype._getNearestStepValue
```

But on this statement it gives me following error

> `sys.extended.ui` is null or not an object

I saw some forums where people suggested to set `CombineScripts="false"` in my ajax toolkit based script manager which I did

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm"  runat="server" CombineScripts="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" 
         LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

but still facing this issue. Why am I unable to have `Sys.Extended` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing in web.config

```
<%@ Outputcache Location="none" %>
```